# Loop to read RGB text files

Tags: java, image, rgb, pixel

I need to be able to choose a .txt file filled with RGB numbers for each pixel, and then create the image using the RGB numbers. I have everything figured out, except I don't know how to create a loop to actually read and set the pixels of the new picture. It's frustrating because I know that it should't be this hard. here is my code so far...

```
public static Picture convertRGBPic()
{
  // set up file for reading
  String fileName = FileChooser.pickAFile();
  File file = new File(fileName);
  // declare an empty picture file
  Picture pic = new Picture();
  try {

    Scanner pictRGB = new Scanner(file);
    int width = pictRGB.nextInt();
    int height = pictRGB.nextInt();



// nested loops to read RGB numbers (no alpha) and set each pixel of the pic below

   for (int row = 0; row < pic.getHeight(); row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < pic.getWidth(); col++)
    {
      Pixel fromPix = pic.getPixel(col , row );
      Pixel toPix = pic.getPixel(col,row); 
      toPix.setRed(fromPix.getRed());
      toPix.setGreen(fromPix.getGreen());
      toPix.setBlue(fromPix.getBlue());
    }
  }


   // end your nested loop

    pictRGB.close(); //close file after reading
  } // end of try and begin catch error if file cannot be read
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch

  return pic;
} // end of method
```

Comment: From where do you take `Picture` and `Pixel`? It isn't likely that a `Picture` created with the default constructor has exactly the width and height on your text file.

Comment: That's my problem. I don't understand how to set the pixels correctly

Comment: Why don't you use `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`?

Comment: That won't be enough.